# jquery dialog works when autoOpen is used, but not when .click is used

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-dialog

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#dialogwindow" ).dialog({
        height: 140,
        width: 400,
        zIndex: 999,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true
    });

    $( ".loginbtn" ).click(function() {
        $("#dialogwindow").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Is linked with:

```
<a class="loginbtn" href="#">Login</a>
```

and the div:

```
<div id="dialogwindow">
<p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

If the dialog has autoOpen: true and no .click event, it works. Once the .click event is added, clicking the link does nothing.

Edit: The test site is located at http://kinnill.com/dev/raymondjames

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/fxMKC/

Comment: That's even more frustrating! I'll edit the post to include a link to the test site where it doesn't work.

Comment: @MWhitmore , try to check console messages, one is: `TypeError: $($anchor.attr("href")).offset() is undefined`

Comment: I've fixed the 'failed to load resource' error, not sure what the other one is from, it isn't coming up on my console..

Comment: The other one appears when you try to click login

Comment: It seems to be based in the easing-based plugin (from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/ ) I have.. I don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: It's because your "Login" is an anchor too in the head.. which you bound the click event to scroll top . Maybe you should use $('#navlinks a') instead of `$('#header a')` so it only binds to your Navigation links

Comment: You're a genius! Works perfectly now. Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment by [Wirey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385672/wirey) I changed the '#header a' string of the erroneous script to '#navlinks a'. The dialog now functions as it should.